# ASP.NET : How to indicate a file outside web directory when Relative URI is expected?

Tags: asp.net

It is possible to create or emulate a virtual directory using C# for load controls (ascx) from a directory outside my web application scope?

Im trying :

```
 UserControl newUserControl = (UserControl)LoadControl( @"D:\" + ascxFileName);
```

Obviously I get runtime exception as the follow : `'D: \ ClaimOutputs \ SolicitudDatoIncorrecto_6.ascx' is not a valid virtual path.`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a virtual directory in your IIS site that points to the other physical location.

There are a lot of security reasons why you can't just directly reference files outside of the directory structure your app is running in.

**UPDATE:**
Can you create a virtual directory in IIS with C#? yes. IIS does have an API. [Creating Virtual directory in IIS with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243600/creating-virtual-directory-in-iis-with-c)

However, the user the site runs under should never have the rights necessary to do that due to security concerns.  You could set it up as a build process, provided you have the rights necessary to do this.

Comment: Before publishing my Website to a IIS Server could I create a virtual directory using C# in runtime, is this a valid solution?

Comment: I need to debug de website before publishing to IIS, so I want to create a VirtualPath Folder or Directory when I launch Application_Start trough VS10 (runtime) so I will do some test...

Comment: @Angel Escobedo: Just set up your local IIS with the appropriate virtual directory.  Publish locally and debug away.