# Create a web application on IIS when using a Web Site (the microsoft version)?

Tags: iis, web, web-applications

sorry for possibly a very stupid question.
I have one of those Visual studio Web Sites ( ie not a web application) , 
is there any way I can automate the creation of the IIS Web Application that points to the web site within Visual Studio ( ie then when developers open the solution, the IIS site will be set up automagically?
Sorry, just not famiiar with the Web Site side of things
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK It's not someting Visual Studio will do out of the box. What you could do is create a batch file that creates the virtual directory then opens the solution. Store it in source control and your developers will be able to run it instead of opening the solution directly.

There are a few options for creating an IIS virtual directory automatically - see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816568) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266026/iis-api-create-virtual-directories).

Also - if you are using VS2005 or above you could change you application to use the development web server instead of IIS and then you won't need to mess around with virtual directories at all. Select 'Use default Web server' on the 'Start Options' section of the projects property pages.