# How to disable ServiceStack redirect on failed authentication?

Tags: servicestack

I am implementing ServiceStack side-by-side with a MVC application. My main application uses form authentication which is configured in my web.config. When the authentication of fails, I don't get the `401 UnAuthorized` as I expect I should. (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073251/743752)

I have added `HtmlRedirect = null` to my `AuthFeature` but this did not work. My request are returning with what is my login page. `~/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fapi%2fauth%2fcredentials`
Im sending my payload as POST with `content-type: application/json`

Is there another way of disabling redirects on failed login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using FormsAuthentication and ServiceStack Authentication in the same application? I think MVC is doing the redirect (not ServiceStack) because you have the `<authentication>` element in your web.config...probably something like...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" />
</authentication>
```

If you don't need FormsAuthentication you can remove this `<authentication>` element from you web.config file.

Comment: And if I do need it for the existing side of the app is there a way to disable it for maybe a location (/ api)?

Comment: Not sure. This -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616524/turning-off-asp-net-webforms-authentication-for-one-sub-directory/8950763#8950763 and this -> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/496 might help

Comment: Fixed with the suggestion of @paaschpa for pointing me in the correct direction. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Form-Hijacking-Prevention